# How do you use power automate to copy one list to another list when the first list contains a column of type person or group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, person-or-group

I have two lists in Sharepoint. My first list has a column of type Person or Group.  I'm new to Power Automate, but I believe it's an array.

I am trying to copy 1 record from the first list into a second list.

During my Create Item step, I'm getting an error.

> OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed. The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: The API operation does not allow writing a value for parameter 'item/Interviewers[0]/DisplayName'. This parameter is read only.

[image: Current State]

I have tried changing the little toggle to detail and to the array setting.  The detail setting puts me into a for each loop which I do not want. Being in a loop at that point will create the record in the new list as many times as there are people in the person or group array (column).

The array setting generates the error above.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the below columns in the Testc list:

- UserName: Single line of text
- Employment Status: Choice
- HR Reviewew: Person or Group
- Notes: Multiple lines of text

[image]

2.Create the same columns in Copy_Testc list as in Testc list

3.Go back Testc list, **Integrate** >> **Power Automate** >> **Create a flow**

[image]

4.Create the following Microsoft Flow

`Note:`Copy_Testc list cannot be empty, there must be an item.

[image]

5.Save and Test this flow

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do all this!!  I believe it is what I'm doing already, with one exception.  HR Reviewers column often has multiple people listed. What happens if you add multiple people in that column, does it still work? Mine does not.